# Infinispan embedded

Tags: maven, infinispan, infinispan-9

I'm just following the [Infinispan embedded tutorial](https://infinispan.org/tutorials/embedded/index.html), at [step 5](https://infinispan.org/tutorials/embedded/step-5/) it doesn't work because of this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No marshaller registered for Java type org.infinispan.tutorial.embedded.LocationWeather
    .
    [some details here]
    .
    .
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.EncoderCache.put(EncoderCache.java:674)
    at org.infinispan.tutorial.embedded.CachingWeatherService.getWeatherForLocation(CachingWeatherService.java:17)
    at org.infinispan.tutorial.embedded.WeatherApp.fetchWeather(WeatherApp.java:50)
    at org.infinispan.tutorial.embedded.WeatherApp.main(WeatherApp.java:69)
```

I was seeking about **how to register the marshaller** [here](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/developing/developing.html#marshalling), but I don't get it, it should be declared at the **pom.xml** or where?

If it is at *pom*, in which part?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the tutorial to work with Infinispan 11 including changes to how marshalling needs to be implemented. I hope this works out for you

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding, I just clone again the repo and follow again the steps, the exception still continuing. Could be my maven or my environment?

Comment: While rebasing one line was lost (the serializationcontext registration). Try now please